# Does php artisan make::auth override existing files if they are present

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I was wondering if php artisan make::auth will override login and registration routes and their corresponding views. I have been following a course based on 5.2 and we implemented login, registration, and password reset from scratch. However, I began the course in 5.4 and ran into a problem where the password reset email link takes me back to the view that sends the email, and not the the view that accepts the new password. I have been tinkering with this for awhile and decided it might be best to just run the built in make::auth scaffolding. I was hoping to get some insight as to how running make::auth would affect my project. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't believe it will, and it will warn you about the files that you have changed.

You should keep your project in source control so that you can test these things yourself and then revert if you break anything. Or at least make a temporary backup of your project so you can test it out first.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer.